# knockout server call doesn't run at all

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Edit: I thought this function was calling the wrong api, however after commenting it out I realize that the function does not work at all. The page was generating the call itself.

So why doesn't this function send a call to the controller at all when the same function without a parameter, and wrapped in Ko.computed works ok?

I am using Knockoutjs and ASP.net MVC 5 to make a webpage. There are two calls to the server passing a parameter one works well, the other never works.

I am using this exercise as a base for my own project. [using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-6](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-6)

I have a single ajax helper from the exercise

```
function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
    self.error(''); // Clear error message
    return $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: uri,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        self.error(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

This function below works and sends **GET /api/Guests/20** using the API of GET api/Guests/{id} returning back data

```
 self.getGuestDetail = function(item) {
    ajaxHelper(guestUri + item.GuestID, "GET").done(function(data) {
        self.detail(data);
    });
```

Yet this function, which is pretty much identical doesn't return any data, basically the same server call is being sent differently.

The api it wants is GET api/RoomBooking?DateFrom={DateFrom} (server side datefrom at this stage is a string)

```
self.RoomList = ko.observableArray(); //an array that will hold each room when foreached ko.computed(
self.ShowFreeRoomsFunction =  function (item) {
    ajaxHelper(roombookingUri + item.BookingFrom, "GET").done(function (data) {
                   self.RoomList(data);
             });
```

I have been looking at this all day, and am totally lost. I have replaced the Datefrom with just simple strings to get something to pass, but it seems as soon as I try to pass a parameter, the method never sees it.

When I don't pass a parameter and wrap in ko.computed the method works returning data.

Here is the same call working by wrapping it in a ko.computed function. It sends off the **GET /api/RoomBooking/** api which is what I want

```
 self.RoomList = ko.observableArray(); //an array that will hold each room when foreached ko.computed(
self.ShowFreeRoomsFunction = ko.computed(function () {
    ajaxHelper(roombookingUri, "GET").done(function (data) {
        self.RoomList(data);
    });
 });
```

Close to Success achieved the url has to be http://localhost:50524/api/RoomBooking/?textA=asdfghjkl with the ? in it. Now all that needs fixing is how to pass the variable to replace asdghjkl and then move dates.

If I manually enter the url into the browser I can see it moving across in fiddler and it returns data as a json file.

But if I try to do it through the program it never shows in fiddler nor runs.

Fiddler result:

> Result Protocol Host URL Body Caching Content-Type Process Comments
>   Custom 51 200 HTTP localhost:50524 /api/RoomBooking/?textA=asdfghjkl
>   117 no-cache; Expires: -1 application/json; charset=utf-8
>   iexplore:10040

What might I be doing wrong in my Get call that stops it ever showing even when hard coded in like this?

```
self.RoomList = ko.observableArray(); //an array that will hold each room when foreach
self.ShowFreeRoomsFunction = function (item) {
    ajaxHelper("/api/RoomBooking/?textA=asdfghj", "GET").done(function (data) {
        self.RoomList(data);
    });
 };
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Can't you just pass data as data? The `ajax` will stringify it. You may need to check that it's all JSON-able data.

Comment: @Roy J Tried that, the main problem seems to be that the past /api/.. gets changed to /createbooking/...

Comment: can you show your api method signature and also if there is any `network error` you get in console?

Comment: Please, do these 2 things to add extra information about your problem: 1) type the full URL in your browser to do a manual GET and see what happens, i.e. what answer or error you get. Testing a GET API call is at easy as that. 2) When you find the succesful format for your GET, check what GET request is being sent by the script, by opening your browsers console with F12. -- Most probably the problem is that the sat has the wrong format. Can you show that format of your date parameter? Can you modify it as a string parameter? Can you show your action's code?

Comment: @Jotabe Success! sort of. After playing around I found the string to be http://localhost:50524/api/RoomBooking/?textA=asdfghjkl    I just need to fix the variable going in now.

Comment: @JotaBe If I manually enter the url into the browser  I can see it moving across in fiddler and it returns dataas a json file.     But if I try to do it through the program it never shows in fiddler nor runs.      # Result Protocol Host URL Body Caching Content-Type Process Comments Custom 
51 200 HTTP localhost:50524 /api/RoomBooking/?textA=asdfghjkl 117 no-cache; Expires: -1 application/json; charset=utf-8 iexplore:10040   
 I